# Restore a PostGIS database cluster properly

Tags: postgis, postgresql

## Context

In order to migrate from [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) `10.12` to `12.2` on a [Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.4/) server, I first uninstall and purge all postgres related stuff then I followed this;

https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

As every major operation on things around system or databases, I took the habit to make some **backups**.

To do this, I used the content that I've found there;

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/upgrading.html

Especially this command in order to dump **all** my databases at once:

```
$ pg_dumpall > outputfile.dump
```

## Errors

After migrating to the new postgres version, I first faced the error that the user `postgres` already exists, which was fixed by commenting the two following lines in the dump file (`outputfile.dump`):

```
$ sed -ne 's/CREATE ROLE postgres/--&/g' outputfile.dump
$ sed -ne 's/ALTER ROLE postgres/--&/g' outputfile.dump
```

### Postgis related error

Of course, then I was confronted with another error, otherwise it would be too easy.
This one is as follows;

```
$ psql -U postgres -f outputfile.dump -v ON_ERROR_STOP=ON
SET
SET
SET
ALTER DATABASE 
CREATE DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE  
REVOKE
GRANT 
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres".
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
 set_config 
------------ 

(1 row)

SET
SET
SET
SET
psql:outputfile.dump:70: ERROR:  schema "topology" already exists
```

So, ... I tried to think about the same thing that before, i.e. commenting the line 70 which is;

```
70:CREATE SCHEMA topology;
```

but... this line actually creates the `topology` schema for [`PostGIS`](https://postgis.net/), which I obviously need as my databases are spatial ones. And indeed, if I comment out those lines, e.g. by:

```
$ sed -ne 's/CREATE SCHEMA topology/--&/g' outputfile.dump
```

I face a `schema "topology" does not exist` error.

The line `CREATE SCHEMA topology` which creates the topology, is followed by these:

```
73:ALTER SCHEMA topology OWNER TO postgres;
76:-- Name: SCHEMA topology; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner: postgres
79:COMMENT ON SCHEMA topology IS 'PostGIS Topology schema';
```

But what is really interesting here, is that the `postgis_topology` extension itself is actually created *after* the previously described lines, e.g. in my case at line 153 for the very first database in the cluster:

```
153:-- Name: postgis_topology; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner:
156:CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis_topology WITH SCHEMA topology;
163:COMMENT ON EXTENSION postgis_topology IS 'PostGIS topology spatial types and functions';
175:-- Data for Name: topology; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: topology; Owner: postgres 
178:COPY topology.topology (id, name, srid, "precision", hasz) FROM stdin; 
183:-- Data for Name: layer; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: topology; Owner: postgres
186:COPY topology.layer (topology_id, layer_id, schema_name, table_name, feature_column, feature_type, level, child_id) FROM stdin;
217:-- Name: topology; Type: SCHEMA; Schema: -; Owner: postgres
220:CREATE SCHEMA topology;
223:ALTER SCHEMA topology OWNER TO postgres;
226:-- Name: SCHEMA topology; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner: postgres
229:COMMENT ON SCHEMA topology IS 'PostGIS Topology schema';
```

These lines obviously repeats each time a PostGIS database has to be restored.

## Question

I wonder why the error about the `topology` schema is raised before (@line 70) the extension is created (@line 156)?
This seems strange to me because I thought the backup file was supposed to be read sequentially.
Could it be possible the dump tool itself (`pg_dumapp`) doesn't work in a proper way, in which case I'd better ask at [dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com) or elsewhere?

Comment: Did you simply rerun that script, or cleaned the DB from any previously created objects (`psql` may not `ROLLBACK` by default, it executes lines in individual transactions)? `sed -ne 'expr' file` does not change anything in the given file; you need to e.g. `sed -i` to make actual changes in place, or `sed 'expr' file > newfile`. However, if it *did* change that file, using the `g` flag after the expression would have made it replace *every occurrence* of the given pattern, which leaves you with no `CREATE SCHEMA topology;` at all.

Comment: And do you *actually* ever used the special topology [functions](https://postgis.net/docs/Topology.html), and *specifically* created any topology? Because you don't *need* the `postgis_topology` extension to have spatially enabled databases! It sounds like you are assuming that?

Comment: Yeah, I know about sed's flags, and everyone who knows how to use it will do the substitution for the `-i` flag naturally. I just don't want newcomers to copy-past a sed line with a `-i` flag in a first try, which would definitely ruins their file if they made any mistake or type. So, yes, I ran it with `-i` instead of `-ne`, of course. About the other question, I'm not sure there was a database in there with special topology; I didn't manage them all actually. I was only told to backup them all using the aforementioned command and to restore them after migrating postgresql to its new version.

Comment: ,-) okay. How about the `/g` flag to the expression? It will comment out all `CREATE SCHEMA topology;` statements, so that it won't exist. You need one of them, and I'd say keep the one that is created by `pg_dump` rather than the one created by adding the extension.